# Broken OpenCL support in nvidia-384

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

OpenCL support after upgrading from `nvida-375` to `nvidia-384` seems to be broken. Specifically the call to `clCreateContext`.

Running `clinfo` with `nvidia-375` results in:

```
NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  NVIDIA CUDA
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [NV]
```

However with `nvidia-384` is seen:

```
NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  NVIDIA CUDA
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [NV]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            <checkNullCtx:2241:create context with device from default platform : error 999>
```

It also not possible to downgrade easily as `nvidia-375` is now a transitional package for `nvidia-385`:

```
$ apt search nvidia-375
nvidia-375/xenial-updates,now 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [residual-config]
  Transitional package for nvidia-384
```

Update: running `clinfo` as root doesn't result in any errors with 384.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `clinfo` under `strace` indentified that `~/.nv` was owned by root.

```
[pid 11593] open("~/.nv/ComputeCache/index", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 11593] open("~/.nv/ComputeCache/index", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 11593] open("~/.nv/ComputeCache/index", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 11593] open("~/.nv/ComputeCache/index", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```